# Uncaugt TypeError accessing JSON data with react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This quesrtion relates to APIs, JSON formatted data and React.js.

I'm attempting to access data from an API for which the output is a JSON array, which is in the following format:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1479498608,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDUSD":1,
    "USDJPY":110.644997,
    "USDCAD":1.351041,
    "USDRUB":64.628403,
    "USDCNY":6.879204,
    "USDMXN":20.623699
  }
}
```

Now the part that I am really interested in is the "quotes" values for various currency pairs.

So, using a `react.js` class:

```
var TickerTrader = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return{};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var component = this;
    $.get("http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=4a368d8077807c97b3aff9415a4d4995&currencies=USD,JPY,CAD,RUB,CNY,MXN&format=1", function(data) {
      component.setState(data);
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>USD/JPY: {this.state.quotes.USDJPY}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

However, this does not seem to work. I was wondering, if I wanted to access the value corresponding to USDJPY, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't so much that the API call isn't updating state, it's that on your initial load `quotes` will be undefined, causing an error. This is actually Javascript related, not React.

```
render: function() {
  // on initial load quotes will be undefined
  return (
    <div>USD/JPY: {this.state.quotes ? this.state.quotes.USDJPY : null}</div>
  );
}
```

Conversely, you could load the initial schema in the state.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    quotes: {}
  };
},
```

Javascript seems to be ok with returning an `undefined` when the property doesn't exist, but it will raise an exception when the object you're accessing the property from is undefined.

```
let foo = {}
foo.test
// undefined
foo.test.fail
// Uncaugt TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Would help if the react.js documentation explained how to access nested arrays. Unless I am mistaken...

Comment: Well `quotes` is an object, not an array... and the issue is actually Javascript, not React :)

Comment: Updated the answer with more info